# change route and content without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How to pass the route in ajax in laravel without form?

I have a `link` or `route` without form.

```
<a href="{{ route('cart', $market->id) }}" class="card-text add-to-cart">Add to cart</a>
```

I want to do it with ajax.

```
<a role="button" class="card-text add-to-cart">Add to cart</a>

<script>
    $('.add-to-cart').on('click', function(){
        window.location.replace("{{ route('cart', $market->id) }}");
        $('#cart').show();
    })
</script>
```

This code refreshes the page. I do not want to refresh the page.

My goal is to make [this](http://tavazostore.com/en/product-list/page/1/pagesize/20) page.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a simple Ajax like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".add_to_cart").on("click", function(event){
    var Route = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST" Or "GET",  
        url: "Your Routue",  
       
    });
});
```

});

i think it will solve your probelm

Comment: Don't forget `event.preventDefault();` or the link will still redirect the user.

Comment: I see this error ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4cwC.png

Comment: didn't you make that method in your controller?